# Oracle Table column name having special( Danish) characters. Unable to execute sql query

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, character

I am using DbDataReader to execute query. Please find the code below

Query is:

```
select BRANCH_NAME, AMOUNT, ACCOUØNT_ID from ACCOUNT
```

Error is:

> ORA-00904: "ACCOU?NT_ID": invalid identifier  .

I am trying to connect oracle database and execute the oracle query.

Please help by how to execute the oracle query which columns have special characters.

Comment: Are you building the query in a variable?   Write out the query the line before and be sure you are sending what you think you are.

Comment: What is NLS_LANGUAGE settings on client?

Answer (score 3):

Quite possibly

```
 select "BRANCH_NAME", "AMOUNT", "ACCOUØNT_ID" from "ACCOUNT";
```

will work.

See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/sql_elements008.htm for more information on Database Object Naming Rules.

Comment: Thanks for your Quick response. I have already tried this. But still i am facing the same problem. Please help.